# Gradle 6.5 not building: ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm building android project with:

- Android Gradle plugin v. :4.1.0-alpha10
- Gradle version: 6.5-rc-1

and getting this error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not create task ':app:extractDeepLinksDebug'.
Cannot obtain value from provider of environment variable 'ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE' at configuration time.
Use a provider returned by 'forUseAtConfigurationTime()' instead.
```

I started getting this error when i updated Gradle version

Now after I downgrade to last to 6.5-milestone-1 it gives me another error:

```
Unsupported method: AndroidArtifact.getBuildConfigFields().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

Now i cannot build my project with any version.

Comment: do you have custom code in your build.gradle?